# Apache POI XSSF - How to add "two levels" of column labels in a pivot table

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have generated PIVOT table using Apache POI 3.14 from the file Test.xlsx
Note:  addColLabel method is from the link from JensGabe. Per the link, This method (a slightly modified version of XSSFPivotTable.addRowLabel) adds a "normal" pivot column label.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
 Connection conn  = null;   
 try
    {

   //Input file 
   XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("Excel_pivot_template_2.xlsx"));

   XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

   XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(new AreaReference(new CellReference("A3"), new CellReference("E11")), new CellReference("I3"));

   //second column from the input file  
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);

   addColLabel(pivotTable, 0);

   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 2);

    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("pivot_output.xlsx");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
    wb.close();
    System.out.println("********* Complete *********** ");
            }
```

Input and output from the program:
[image: Input and output from the program]

Expected output:
[image: Expected Output]

Any help is greatly appreciated.I haven't had any success yet.

Comment: Here is the link for implementation of  addColLabel method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36456468/6256710